# RexsterClient( RexPro from JAVA) connections to Rexster Server going to 'CLOSE_WAIT' status

Tags: java, neo4j, tinkerpop, rexster

After my ingestion(through RexsterClient) to graph DB starts, RexsterClient connection works fine for some time. Later RexsterClient (RexPro) takes a lot of time to respond. When I open a new connection for every timeout that I get from ingestion, after a few reconnections, the TCP connection goes into 'CLOSE_WAIT' and I am not able to reconnect later.Thereafter RexsterClient does not respond to any queries.
The queries from REST interface eg:

```
localhost:8182/graphs/neo4jsample/tp/gremlin?script=g.v(0).out
```

gives results in good response time.

On the other hand, if I do not open new connections when it takes a lot of time to respond, I get 'queue size exceeded' error (as the writes to Rexster fail).

I am using Neo4j2 graph

Comment: any errors in the rexster logs/console output?

Comment: No errors. In the Messages.log, I was getting something like '[GC:Monitor] : waiting for another 3000mS'

Comment: [unable to edit the above comment] 
On digging deeper I found that Full GC is occurring back to back as Older Generation Heap is filled up. It is not throwing an 'out of memory' exception as the Young Generation heap is not getting filled. It seems all that I am ingesting into graph is being cached in Memory and not being removed by GC once it is persisted into graph.
I have alloted 12 GB heap to Rexster but it seems ~11 GB of the Older Gen Heap is filled up and is remaining so even after Full GC.
Is this normal behaviour?

Comment: sounds strange - it's as though transactions aren't committing somehow, but Rexster should be managing the transactions and committing on each successful request (unless you're doing it some other way).

Comment: @stephenmallette Thanks for the reply! I did the ingestion into graph with manual commit after 30000 vertices. After some time, again the threads started timing out. Now, if I ingest from another machine, the server allows successful ingestion! Seems strange.
With regard to the Old Generation Heap getting filled up, I read Neo4j server will utilize the whole heap available for caching graph. Will this be the same with Rexster? 
Could you tell me if there is a way to set neo4j cache_type in Rexster? That tag is not there in rexster.xml  
Also, can Rexster be configured with enterprise Neo4j?

Comment: And this message is coming back to back in the messages.log 
`INFO  [org.neo4j]: GC Monitor: Application threads blocked for an additional 21838ms [total block time: 22517.229s]`

Comment: All of those rexster configurations for neo4j are just pass through to neo4j itself.  So, if there is a setting you want to use, just add it to rexster.xml and it should get there.  Rexster's memory usage is generally driven by the graphs that it hosts so you have to give it a fair amount to cover the graphs you have.  That error is definitely neo4j related but I'm not sure what's happening to get it into that state.

Comment: @stephenmallette The Rexster Client log says 
`Message received response timeoutConnection (3600000 s)`
Had set the time out as 1 hour.
Digging into the RexsterClient source code, I observed the exception being thrown from the if condition    `if (resultMessage == null)` 
So, as no was message was found in the ArrayBlockingQueue responseQueue for 3600s , it threw the timeout error. 
Could you pls give me some direction to troubleshoot this further?

Comment: @stephenmallette started observing this issue when I started using parallel ingestion into multiple (neo4j2) graphs hosted on the same Rexster Server

Comment: is this on rexster 2.6.0?

Comment: @stephenmallette Yes, Rexster2.6.0 and Neo4j2 as instructed in the Specific Graph Configurations for Rexster on Github

Comment: @stephenmallette  As you would know, the Blueprints tag/2.5.0 uses neo4j version 2.0.1 in its pom for blueprints-neo4j2 whereas latest (2.6.0) Blueprints uses neo4j version 2.2.1.  I am using 'checkout tag/2.5.0' as instructed on the Github page.Will that be a relevant difference?

Comment: yeah - mis-matching versions might be hurting you - but that might not be your only problem.  we've been stuck for a while in editing the wiki as there is a bug in github that screws up all the hyperlinks when we save it - textile formatting is off.  I've reported the bug but it hasn't been fixed yet after a few weeks. :(

Comment: just as a side note, i'm not sure where you are in your development but note that TinkerPop 3.x is the latest incarnation of The TinkerPop Stack - Rexster and the rest of TinkerPop 2.x is in maintenance mode at this point.  Neo4j 2.x is supported directly in TP 3.0 - no support of 1.x.  Anyway, all current TinkerPop development is happening over there now: http://tinkerpop.incubator.apache.org/docs/3.0.0-incubating/

Comment: @stephenmallette Thank you for the quick responses! Will have to try a demo with the 2.6.0 Blueprints. Tracking the developments in TinkerPop 3 as well.